# Tor is running but service not listening

Tags: configuration, help

I installed tor on a linux mint fresh install (18 - Sarah Cinnamon - to use with proxychains, with default settings too), with default settings. Tor service is started, but it does not appear listening on port 9050 when I put netstat -vantup (or ss). Iptables is disabled. When I try use proxychains (for example, proxychains firefox), the console shows me "|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout". In a station with Ubuntu, I did same installation,  and works fine. Someone can help me to identify what can happend? Thanks in advance

Comment: is `tor` actually running? does it appear in the process list?

Comment: also what does your tor log say? normally located at `/var/log/tor/log`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.... 1-although the service appear as active ( /etc/init.d tor status - shows "active" ) , the process is not listed as " running " in htop  #### 2 - at /var/log/tor/ was not log files, the folder is empty.... : (

Comment: there may be something broken in mints packaging then? you could try installing from the official tor repos using the upstream ubuntu codename that mint is based on, found with something like `lsb_release -u -a` then following the [instructions on the torproject site](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html#ubuntu) for the ubuntu codename in question.

Comment: Thanks again @canonizing-ironize... I tried install like instructions on torproject site, same problem. I added ubuntu repos on sources.list to download from these repos, but not working yet. Correcting my previous comment, the result of tor status is "active (exited)". As the os installation is "clean", I'll try install tor again from zero, including by source code, if does not work, I'll remake the os install. Thank you for attention!

Comment: Please edit your `torrc` (usually found at `/etc/tor/torrc`) and enter the line `Log info file /var/log/tor/log`. When you saved the file start the Tor process again and tell us what is in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same issue in the same Linux Mint version.
According to this bug report, it affects all recent Debian releases: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808296

The report suggests as a workaround to disable the apparmor config in the service file:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/tor@default.service.d/
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "[Service]\nAppArmorProfile=" > /etc/systemd/system/tor@default.service.d/override.conf'
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service tor restart
```

Worked for me ;-)

Comment: Don't disable apparmor, enable apparmor instead https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12518/autostart-tor-on-linux-mint-ubuntu

Comment: Hi all! Sorry for delay to response... I added Tor service to start at cron, and it worked for me. Thanks all